# Restringir acceso Firebase Database a la aplicación android

Tags: java, android, firebase, nosql

He leído sobre las reglas de autentificación:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Y hasta una pregunta sobre el mismo tema en firebase:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818782/restrict-firebase-database-access-to-one-android-app

Pero no encuentro una solución a mi problema, actualmente tengo las reglas de lectura y escritura a True. Por lo que la gente solo necesita la direccion https://xxxx.firebaseio.com para acceder a los datos. La forma de evitarlo que encuentro son:

- Poner las reglas a false, la cual no me sirve ya que no puedo acceder tampoco desde la app.
- Restringir el acceso de la api a la app android, https://console.developers.google.com/ lo cual no funciona, ya que sigo accediendo mediante el enlace y la app.
- Poner las reglas del modo  "auth.uid === $user_id" lo cual tampoco me vale, ya que no quiero ningún tipo de autentificación en la aplicación.

En resumen, quiero que solo la app pueda acceder a Firebase Database sin que los usuarios tengan que autentificarse en dicha app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar la [autenticación anónima](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) para tu app, no requiere que el usuario ingrese credenciales, y permite mantener segura la conexión con Firebase.

Por otro lado, con las [funciones "callables"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) de Firebase Functions, puedes hacer que sólo desde tu app se puedan hacer llamados a tu function.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer eso podrías usar Cloud Functions. Por ejemplo, mandar algún token que tenga solo la aplicación y verificarlo antes de mandar los datos: [CloudFunctions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions)

Pero ojo que ese código estará igual en el celular de cada uno de tus usuarios, de cualquier forma alguien con ese código podría acceder directo al link (con Postman por ejemplo) sin necesidad de descargar la aplicación.

Si tienes datos que deben ser protegidos en tu aplicación, debes usar autenticación.